# How do I ask again for user's age if the user did not correctly put their age into console?

Tags: java

I am currently studying Java from the very beginning.

While I was doing some practices, I came across with this program challenge where I could not figure out what to do.

The program simply asks user's age and name.

It checks the age whether it is less than 0 and if it is, it asks user to input correct age and once the user have inserted correct age, it moves on to ask for the user's name

but I couldn't figure out how to implement this.

Below is the code I wrote and if I run this, it shows the message "Wrong age. Please input correct age." and asks for user's name right away.

Can someone guide me with this please?

Thank you very much.

```
public class Person {
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public void setAge(int _age) {

        if (_age < 0) {
            System.out.println("Wrong age. Please input correct age.");
            return;
        }

        age = _age;
    }

    public void setName(String _name) {
        name = _name;
    }


    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example02 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        Person p1 = new Person();
        System.out.println("Please enter the age: ");
        p1.setAge(scan.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Please enter the name: ");
        p1.setName(scan.next());

        Person p2 = new Person();
        System.out.println("Please enter the age: ");
        p2.setAge(scan.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Please enter the name: ");
        p2.setName(scan.next());

        System.out.println(p1.getName() + " / " + p1.getAge());
        System.out.println(p2.getName() + " / " + p2.getAge());
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a polite `do... while()` loop.

Comment: What you're looking for is called a "loop".  Starting with the condition that a valid age is not known, loop over the operation of asking the age until a valid age is known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code fragment

```
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter the age: ");
    p1.setAge(scan.nextInt());
} while(p1.getAge() < 0);
```

Comment: This will work if age is initialized in the class Person: `int age = -1;`.

Comment: Thank you very much!  :D

Comment: @StephaneM This will even work if `age` is initialized with any value, as while the condition is checked when the body in `do` block is executed

Answer (score 0):

You should use loop for this.

You can change the definition of `setAge()` as following:

```
public boolean setAge(int _age) {

    if (_age < 0) {
        System.out.println("Wrong age. Please input correct age.");
        return false;
    }

    age = _age;
    return true;
}
```

and calling as following:

```
while(!p1.setAge(scan.nextInt()));
...
while(!p2.setAge(scan.nextInt()));
```

Following is complete code. See it [working here](https://ideone.com/22Jtlz):

```
class Person {
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public boolean setAge(int _age) {

        if (_age < 0) {
            System.out.println("Wrong age. Please input correct age.");
            return false;
        }

        age = _age;
        return true;
    }

    public void setName(String _name) {
        name = _name;
    }


    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}

class Example02 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        Person p1 = new Person();
        System.out.println("Please enter the age: ");
        while(!p1.setAge(scan.nextInt()));
        System.out.println("Please enter the name: ");
        p1.setName(scan.next());

        Person p2 = new Person();
        System.out.println("Please enter the age: ");
         while(!p2.setAge(scan.nextInt()));
        System.out.println("Please enter the name: ");
        p2.setName(scan.next());

        System.out.println(p1.getName() + " / " + p1.getAge());
        System.out.println(p2.getName() + " / " + p2.getAge());
    }
}
```